# confusionMatrix function and different sized matrices

Tags: r, matrix, confusion-matrix

I'm working with the confusionMatrix function using the caret package. The function works perfectly fine with a 2x2 (or 5x5 etc.) matrix. Example:

Table1:

```
   1  2
1 25 15
2  8 33

confusionMatrix(Table1) -> works!
```

But if I have a different sized table:

Table2:

```
    5   6   7
3   1   1   0
4   8   5   0
5 153  57   3
6  57 105  19
7   6  27  27
8   0   3   6

confusionMatrix(Table2) -> Won't work!
Error: Error in !all.equal(nrow(data), ncol(data)) : invalid argument type
```

How can I bypass this trouble since I'm forced to use the confusionMatrix function?

Comment: Not knowing about that package or function: is there not a compelling/intuitive reason why the input should be a square matrix? Since that's what it seems to be complaining about.

Comment: Yes but I can't always have square matrixes. Thats what I'm asking about :/

Comment: Is it a matter of adding two columns of zeroes with colnames `3` and `4`? How did you create Table2, using `table()`?

Comment: flodel yes, 3 and 4 are magically missing. And yes, I have used table() for Table2. How do I add those two columns of zeroes?

Comment: Assuming you used `table(x, y)`, can you please provide `class(x)` and `class(y)`? (last question, we're almost there.)

Comment: table(Prediction, Test$quality), I did it like that. Quality is the last column in my dataset which determines the quality of the product.

Comment: Then please tell what `class(Prediction)` and `class(Test$quality)` both return.

Comment: Prediction = [1] "numeric". Test$quality = [1] "integer"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- as.integer(Prediction)
y <- Test$quality
l <- union(x, y)
Table2 <- table(factor(x, l), factor(y, l))
confusionMatrix(Table2)
```

The idea was to convert your inputs to `table` to two factors that share the exact same levels (`l`). Then you are guaranteed that `Table2` will be square.

Comment: By Gods you did it! Thank you a lot!